# tomcat8 slow and inaccessible after windows server upgrade from 2012 to 2016

Tags: java-8, tomcat8

We have two apps environnements (dev and qualification) running under windows server 2012
every environnement have two servers with multiples tomcat 8 instances , and all the stuff is load balanced with HAProxy

the problem
after windows upgrade from 2012 to 2016 starting with the dev environnment we noticed a slow response after a few days of worload, and at the end the servers won't even respond .
restarting the services is also slow and sometimes we need to kill the processes to avoid blocking wait, and after service restart all become OK for a few days
we thought it's HAProxy but event when we call the apps directly , it takes time to see http calls in tomcat access logs and the response is slow , sometimes it does not respond and we don't even seen any http calls.
the old configuration(under server 2012) worked very well for years .

I did
Gatling workload Tests (all OK after services fresh restart)
JVM monitoring All OK (threads memory cpu)